# Modify the `edit` binary in os x to a different editor

Tags: macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh, launch-services

On the command line, I can type `edit <folder/file name>` and it will open in TextWrangler, which I haven't used in ages. I'm not sure how the `edit` binary got there — I use oh-my-zsh, potentially relevant. I wanted to change `subl` to `edit` (nicer to type) and discovered it already existed.

I uninstalled TextWrangler and now I get the error

```
edit: error: -10814
    LaunchServices could not locate your copy of TextWrangler.
```

I've been looking around for how to modify the LaunchServices database and I've rebuilt it but I still get the error. Running `which edit` gives me `/usr/local/bin/edit` fwiw.

What controls this association and how can I switch it to Sublime Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to run `ls -al /usr/local/bin/edit` you'd see this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  52 Apr 15  2012 /usr/local/bin/edit -> /Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/Helpers/edit
```

Therefore, it looks like `edit` is a built-in command-line program for TextWrangler, just like `subl` is for Sublime, or `mate` is for TextMate. Of course, there's nothing stopping you from deleting the symlink, then making a new one pointing to `subl` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

To switch, you can run the following commands:

```sh
rm /usr/local/bin/edit
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/edit
```

In my case, I had replaced TextWrangler for BBEdit, so I just did those commands but with `/Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/Helpers/bbedit_tool` instead of the Sublime (`subl`) one.